# VBA Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vba, excel

I am trying to connect to `mysql` using `Excel VBA`, I am using Excel 2013. I am new to VB, so i followed this example: [Inserting Data Into MySQL From Excel Using VBA](http://www.heritage-tech.net/908/inserting-data-into-mysql-from-excel-using-vba/)

Here is my connection code:

```
Private Sub ConnectDB()
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1.13 Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=123.456.0.188;" & _
    "DATABASE=MyDB;" & _
    "USER=MyUser;" & _
    "PASSWORD=MyPassword;" & _
    "Option=3"
End Sub
```

When I try to execute this code, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':

Automation error
Unspecified error
```

Here are my references:

[image: VBA References]

I know this question may look like a duplicate but I have looked through most of questions similar to this one, they do not solve my issue.

Comment: Is the mysql odbc driver installed?

Comment: @AndréSchild Yes i see `MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1` in my programs and features

Comment: And it's the correct 32 or 64bit edition as needed by your VBA application? Does it work when you try to setup the datasource in the odbc manager?

Comment: problem solved, so i checked my programs and files and i noticed that i had 32bit mysql and 64bit MySQL connector, so i downloaded the 32bit myql connector to match 32bit mysql and it worked. @AndréSchild make your comment an answer and i will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ODBC drivers must match the 32 or 64Bit architekture of the VBA application.

Otherwise VBA isn't able to use the odbc drivers.