# Cannot connect to MySQL Server from workstation in different region

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, macros

I have a macro that pulls information from a MySQL server. This macro is accessed from different workstations in different regions. When I run it from my computer (Workstation A) it works perfectly. However, we setup new computers in other regions (Workstation B) and here is giving me a **Connection String** problem.

Workstation B is set up the same way Workstation A was set up. Using same Windows version (64 bit) and same Excel version (32 bit). Both Workstations have MySQL driver installed and ODBC connector, but still Workstation B is having issues to connect.

This is the MySQL Connection String I'm using:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=server.name.com;Port=3306;Database=db;User=macro;Password=********;
```

And this is the moment when it launches the error:

```
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

On Error GoTo Error_Handler1
oConn.Open strConn
On Error GoTo 0
```

The error I get is:

> Run-time error '-2147457259 (800004005) Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found. (MySQL OBDC 5.3 ANSI Driver, C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector ODBC 5.3\myodbc5a.dll

This is the same Connection String I'm using in Workstation A and it's working.

However, I test my connection using these parameters from the ODBC Data Source Administrator and it works just fine. The connection is perfect.

Do you guys know a reason why this could not be working for some computers under the same configuration and others not?

I would highly appreciate any ideas people may have - thanks.

Comment: error message??

Comment: In MYSQL, the database admin can restrict users based on the domain name also. Does both workstation is in the same domain? Your DB administrator will be able to help you.

Comment: Run-time error '-2147457259 (800004005)':

Comment: @Barney my username in the DB can be run from any domain without restrictions. I checked already

Comment: Try disabling offline files as per: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/09/01/odbc-microsoft-access-driver-is-not-a-valid-path/

Comment: @nbayly Thanks. I already sent the link to my IT department. However, I would think the problem is related to the MySQL Versions installed. The error continue as follows: "Sepecified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found. (MySQL OBDC 5.3 ANSI Driver, C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\\Connector ODBC 5.3\myodbc5a.dll).

Comment: Every machine attempting this connection must have the [MySQL ODBC Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) installed beforehand. Choose appropriate one for OS and bit version.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this part that i copied in your MySQL Code `Port=3306Database=db` you forgot to add `;` between them. I think this is the cause of error

and also to add based on link here [VBA Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153613/vba-run-time-error-2147467259-80004005)

Is the reference installed is the correct 32bit or 64bit as needed?

Comment: I corrected that in the question as I noticed it too. I think this may just be a typo in the question as OP already states that connection string works on Workstation A.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. After a lot of communication between my IT manager and I, we agreed that the problem was in the versions used for MySQL, 32B vs 64B. Workstation B  has a 64B OS system but a 32B Office Package.

My recommendation is to install both MySQL drivers, 32B & 64B. That solved my problem.

For more valuable info follow this post:
[excel vba mysql ado connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736522/excel-vba-mysql-ado-connection)